# function to identify whether the value can be converted to int, or double, or anything else?

Tags: java

If there is a string variable containing a number string , is there any function to identify whether the value can be converted to int, or double, or anything else?? i need the function name in java

Comment: I'm a little confused, wouldn't this be testing if the number is comprised of only numbers, and a decimal point?

Comment: @Bucco if ( variable=="India") then convert to string

if (variable=="562") then convert to int

if (variable=="54.3354") then convert to double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String sent3 = "123";
 System.out.println(sent3.matches("[0-9]+"));

System.out.println(sent3.matches("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"));// for double
```

**output** :- true

If the output is `true` then it can be converted into int.

[Follow this link for more regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: False. That matches when `sent3 = "123456789000"` which cannot be converted into an `int`. Also, your regex does not handle `-` signs

Comment: Yes it prints true. I was saying that your statement was false. Try parsing "123456789000" into an `int`. Its value is too large (greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: @AJ.I know to how to do the decimal checking, but how i will differentiate the type, wether it is double or float?

Comment: @Quincunx every one know the range to be given for parsing.

Comment: @AJ. Take note that your double check does not work. It accepts `"."` or other strings with multiple periods. Also, it is equivalent to `"[.0-9]+"`.

Comment: @Quincunx - This is not working                                                             Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
      if (m.matches()) {
        Double.parseDouble(string);
      }

Comment: @Quincunx now I noticed that

Comment: @Vizllx sorry but you can't differentiate the decimal value in float or double

Comment: @AJ: you haven't escaped a dot in your second regexp and it will accept ANY character in this place. So `111k555` will return `true` as well

Comment: @Adassko ooh! noticed

Answer (score 1):

```
String test = "1234";
System.out.println(test.matches("-?\\d+"));
test = "-0.98";
System.out.println(test.matches("-?\\d+\\.\\d+"));
```

The first one matches (ie prints true) any **integer** (not `int`, integer) with an optional `-` sign in front. The second one matches any `double` value with an optional `-` sign, at least one digit before a required decimal point, and at least on digit following the decimal point.

Also, the function name is `String.matches` and it uses regular expressions.

Comment: @Quincunx- Thanks for answering, I am trying all the solution provided by everybody, I will let you know..

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves trying to parse the string into the various types, and then looking for exceptions that Java might throw. This is probably an inefficient solution, but the code is relatively short.

```
public static Object convert(String tmp)
{
    Object i;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            i = Double.parseDouble(tmp);
        } catch (Exception p) {
            return tmp; // a number format exception was thrown when trying to parse as an integer and as a double, so it can only be a string
        }
        return i; // a number format exception was thrown when trying to parse an integer, but none was thrown when trying to parse as a double, so it is a double
    }
    return i; // no numberformatexception was thrown so it is an integer
}
```

You can then use this function with the following lines of code:

```
String tmp = "3"; // or "India" or "3.14"
Object tmp2 = convert(tmp);
System.out.println(tmp2.getClass().getName());
```

You can convert the function into inline code to test if it is an integer, for example:

```
String tmp = "3";
Object i = tmp;
try {
    i = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

I was a little sloppy and tried to catch normal Exceptions, which is rather generic - I suggest you use "NumberFormatException" instead.